# How do i hide the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a program that flip cards and you can create new ones... there is 3 components. App, CardEditor and CardViewer. In CardEditor i want to make a function that hides the button to go to CardViewer before I have typed data. The data is getting stored as state in App.js and sent as props to CardEditor.js. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './CardEditor.css';



class CardEditor extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            front: "",
            back: "",
            showButton : false
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name] : event.target.value
        })
    }
    addCard = () => {
        this.props.addCard(this.state.front, this.state.back);
        this.setState({
            front : "",
            back: ""
        });
    }
    deleteCard = (event) => {
        this.props.deleteCard(event.target.dataset.index);
    }
    showButton = (event) => {
        let showButton = event.target.value;
        this.setState({showButton});
    }

  render() {

    const row = this.props.cards.map((card, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{card.front}</td>
                <td>{card.back}</td>
                <td><button data-index={index} onClick={this.deleteCard}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        );
    })



    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Card Editor</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Front</th>
                    <th>Back</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {row}
            </tbody>
       </table>
       <br />
       <input onChange={this.handleChange} name="front" placeholder="front of card" value={this.state.front}/>
       <input onChange={this.handleChange} name="back" placeholder="back of card" value={this.state.back}/>
       <button onClick={this.addCard}>Add card</button>
        <hr />
        <div style={{display : this.state.showButton === "" ?'none' : 'block'}}>
            <button onClick={this.props.switchMode}>Go to viewer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardEditor;
```

The button is in the "div" below "hr". I try with setState and display "none", but the button still shows...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style={{display : this.state.showButton === false ? 'none' : 'block'}}>
        <button onClick={() => {
             this.setState({showButton: false}) 
             this.props.switchMode()
         }}>Go to viewer</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just calling the function `this.deleteCard()`, why don't you bind the function instead to the event?

For example:

```
onClick={this.deleteCard.bind(this)}
```

If it doesn’t work, try initializing the bind statement from the constructor and simply use `this.deleteCard` from `onclick` event.

Also, this may help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: The delete function works. You do not have to bind to this, when you use an arrow function.

Comment: Nice. So that means this problem has been solved? Feel free to ask if you have any questions. Please vote for the best answer or if there’s not, you may post the correct answer. :)

Comment: It has been solved. :) Thank you for showing interest.

Answer (score 0):

- 1st method

  ```
  this.state.showButton &&
  <div>
  <button onClick={this.props.switchMode}>Go to viewer</button>
  </div>
  ```
- 2nd method

  ```
  style={{ display : this.state.showButton ? 'block' : 'none' }}
  ```

Comment: But do i do the showButton right... I would really like to update it with the props so that it shows that the new state is empty or not.

Comment: For just showing and hiding, both the code which I have mentioned will work.
I didn't understand what you meant by update button with props. Please elaborate

Comment: I used 2nd method, but the point is that if the array this.props.cards is empty, i want to show 'none', otherwise i want to show 'block'.

Comment: this.props.cards is made form cards= this.state.cards in app.js

Comment: you can see the whole code @ https://github.com/Danielhoifodt/cardcreator

Comment: style={{ display : this.props.cards.length ? 'block' : 'none' }}

How about this?
That condition will give 'block' only if the array is non-empty otherwise none.

Comment: It could work, but I found another solution. I made a error message instead. So i did not get the error. You can see the code on github. Thanks for all the posts.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad you got a solution. Please Vote my answer, if you felt it was useful. Thanks.

Comment: I voted, but it will not be recorded util i get 15 points(or something).

Answer (score -1):

I got around the problem by making a error message with alert()before they entered CardVieweer.... it was an easy fix, i woldu like to do it the more cool way, but I will not bother with that now.

If you want to see the app go to http://www.daniel.hoifodt.com/cardcreator.html.

It is not 100% written by me, I got some code from cs50 course and form a github account.

Anywas, the rest is done by be. Also check out the website www.daniel.hoifodt.com it is in Norwegian though. Just so you know.